# LangChain StructuredOutputParser: Unexpected XXX character error while parsing

Tags: json, parsing, openai-api, langchain

I’m using Langchain’s [StructuredOutputParser](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/output_parsers/#structured-output-parser-with-zod-schema) to return generated output in a format I want; in this case, a list of strings.

However, I'm getting an error

> Unexpected XXX character after JSON

when it's parsing the generated output. I initially thought it was because it included double quotation mark (") that breaks the string parsing, but I don't think it's the case for "non-whitespace" character.

[image]

Has anyone encountered a similar error?

Full code

```
const parser = StructuredOutputParser.fromZodSchema(
    z.object({
      paragraphs: z.array(z.string()).describe("list of paragraphs in order"),
      questions: z
        .array(z.string())
        .describe("list of reading comprehension questions in order"),
    })
  );

  const formatInstructions = parser.getFormatInstructions();

  const prompt = new PromptTemplate({
    template:
      "Follow the instruction as best as possible.\n{format_instructions}\n{prompt}",
    inputVariables: ["prompt"],
    partialVariables: { format_instructions: formatInstructions },
  });

  const model = new OpenAI({
    openAIApiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY,
    temperature: 0,
  });

  const parseChain = async () => {
    const input = await prompt.format({
      prompt: `Generate a three paragraph story about a murder mystery in columbia university in ${targetLang}, along with one reading comprehension question for each paragraph. Do not use double quotation at any point.`,
    });
    const response = await model.call(input);
    console.log(response);
    const cleanResponse = (response: string) => {
      // Remove non-whitespace characters
      const cleanedResponse = response.replace(/[^\s]/g, "");
      return cleanedResponse;
    };

    const parsed = parser.parse(response);
    return parsed;
  };
```

I also noticed this is the only library I found so far despite my assumption that a lot of other LLM developers would want their result to be returned in a structured, controlled way. Are there any alternative library to accomplish the same function?